# Pushing air downwards using a fan, to hover in air

Tags: forces, electricity, aerodynamics

I believe that I am simply missing something over here, but cannot find it.
I want to just think theoretically, that if I use a fan (drone manner) to push air downwards, like a rocket, I would be pushed upwards.

So I need to apply a constant force of  upwards. In my case, it's 700N approx.

Now, much electrical power would be needed for the job?

Comment: The power depends a lot on the diameter of your fan and how you compensate for torque. Provide more detail and you will get better answers. A bit of your own effort would be nice, too, so we know at which level to start.

Comment: I understood some things after I had asked the question

I would be pushing air downwards, so the power = Force x velocity
Force = density of air x cross-sectional area of fan x velocity of air^2/time

as I had derived it, but not very sure

and this would be a very rough estimate of the experiment yet, I'll try observing in real-life, by creating a prototype model

Can you suggest some materials, that I could use for the fans? I was thinking cardboard and hot glue gun

Answer (score 1):

If you use a single fan, it will not only accelerate air downwards but also add a bit of swirl. Just as the downward acceleration results in an upward force (the desired lift), the rotational acceleration will result in a torque on the fan and motor assembly, so it will start to rotate in the opposite direction of the fan's rotation.

Either you use an even number of fans and create counter-rotating pairs of them, or you add some device to produce counter-torque. In most helicopters of the Sikorsky type this is a small vertical rotor at the end of a tailboom, or it is a jet of air (Google for NOTAR to learn more).

Once this is solved, start with the [static thrust equation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/is-there-any-equation-to-bind-velocity-thrust-and-power/8822#8822) of a propeller:

$$T_0 = \frac{P\cdot\eta_{Prop}\cdot\eta_{el}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot T_0}{\pi\cdot d_P^2\cdot\rho}}} = \sqrt[\LARGE{3\:}]{P^2\cdot\eta_{Prop}^2\cdot\eta_{el}^2\cdot\pi\cdot \frac{d_P^2}{2}\cdot\rho}$$

Nomenclature:
$\kern4mm T_0\kern7mm$Thrust at zero forward speed
$\kern4mm P\kern8mm$Motor power
$\kern4mm \eta_{Prop}\kern2mm$propeller efficiency. Could be anything between 0.5 and 0.85
$\kern4mm \eta_{el}\kern6mm$electric efficiency of motor and its controller
$\kern4mm d_P\kern6mm$propeller diameter
$\kern4mm \rho\kern9mm$air [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density)
$\kern4mm \pi\kern9mm$3.14159265…

Comment: This is quite advanced for me right now, it will take me some time to understand everything you wrote, so should I do anything to this question until then, or just leave it alone, and get back to studying the concepts? @peter

Comment: @ShubhamGoel To me it seems you will definitely need to study more. And do not rely on cardboard and hotmelt glue to lift yourself.

Comment: Not to lift myself, that's a project for much later, I was talking about the first prototype of lifting a mass of a kg maybe, but anyway, yes I need to study a lot more and will do  @PeterKämpf

Answer (score 0):

The required power is

$$W=\sqrt{\frac{\left ( mg \right )^{3}}{2pS}}$$

-S being the surface of the disc enclosing the fan

-g being gravity acceletation

-p is density of air (kg/m3)

-m is the mass being lifted

The demonstration is [Rankine-Froude theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_de_la_quantit%C3%A9_de_mouvement), which relies on [Bernouilli's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) in the air column of the fan to show that

$$T=2psv^{2}$$

-T being the lifting force

-v being the induced speed of air at the fan

From there you get in stationnary flight that gravity=lift:

$$mg=2psv^{2}$$
or
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{mg}{2pS}}$$

Then by multiplying the speed with the force(=mg) you get the power W in the first equation.

In your specific case you can replace "mg" by 700 N